# Problems getting tinymce 3.4.7 to run

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I downloaded tinymce 3.4.7, did all the required stuff given in "For Dummies" but it seems even that is not enough. after I add all that code to the head of my HTML page it only gives a text area that is in the body of the page. it should give a full text editor similar to the given example in the package but it is not working for me following is the link I am using. not really working for me.
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/For_Dummies

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:/tinymce_3.4.7/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            plugins: "emotions,spellchecker,advhr,insertdatetime,preview",

            // Theme options - button# indicated the row# only
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,|,code,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3: "insertdate,inserttime,|,spellchecker,advhr,,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing: true
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="show.php">
        <p>
            <textarea name="content" cols="50" rows="15">This is some content that will be editable with TinyMCE.</textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can't help you without example code. I'm very interested how following the [for dummies](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22) led to a non-working page.

Comment: Would you please share your code. JsFiddle.net would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please give us your code (JS + HTML).
A common mistake is to try JS code localy ( file://c:... ).
Browsers often have stronger security that blocks JS when launched localy.

Comment: that is total code. please visit the following link give 5 mins to read this http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/For_Dummies

Comment: Did you run it locally (file://) or on a server (http://) even a local server (http://127.0.0.1/...) ?